# How do I increment a variable based off of a given string?

Tags: sql

**Requirements:**

First off, I have a few requirements: This can't use a pre-existing table and must use the declare statement.

**Problem:**

I want to have a function that returns a new unique ID per-name in this format: A1, where A represents the first letter in their name and 1 represents an ID generated for them. Here's a scenario, I have 3 employees, Aaron, Baron and Caron and they're the first employees I've hired, so my function would return this for the given values:

```
Aaron > A1
Baron > B1
Caron > C1
```

and later on I want to hire a guy named Charles, where the ID generated for him will be:

```
Charles > C2
```

**Conclusion:**

I know this can be easily achieved using a table and updates but I'd like to know if this is possible using only variables.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle I would create 26 sequences (seq_a, seq_b, ... seq_z) and a function that dynamically returns generated values from them, for example (pseudo-code):

```sql
create or replace function get_abc_sequence(p_name in varchar2) return varchar2 as
   n int;
   s_seq varchar2(1);
begin
   s_seq:=upper(substr(p_name,1,1));
   case 
       when s_seq between 'A' and 'Z'
          then execute immediate 'select seq_'||s_seq||'.nextval from dual' into n;
       else raise value_error;
   end case;
   return s_seq||to_char(n,'tm9');
end;
```